# Merging two NSRegularExpression

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to add every word from the `stringWithHashtags` into the `attString` that starts with `@` and `#`. As I think the easiest way would be merging the two `NSRegularExpression` and then assign it to the array. Actually I'm assigning them after each other like this:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"#(\\w+)" options:0 error:&error];

NSRegularExpression *regexM = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"@(\\w+)" options:0 error:&error];

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:stringWithHashtags options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, stringWithHashtags.length)];
matches = [regexM matchesInString:stringWithHashtags options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, stringWithHashtags.length)];
```

And in the results only mentions are blue.(It works perfectly only with hashtags)

Here's my full method:

```
-(NSMutableAttributedString*)detectHashtags:(NSString *)stringWithHashtags{

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"#(\\w+)" options:0 error:&error];

    NSRegularExpression *regexTag = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"@(\\w+)" options:0 error:&error];

    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:stringWithHashtags options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, stringWithHashtags.length)];
    matches = [regexTag matchesInString:stringWithHashtags options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, stringWithHashtags.length)];

    NSMutableAttributedString *attString= [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stringWithHashtags];

    NSInteger stringLength= [stringWithHashtags length];

    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {

        NSRange wordRange = [match rangeAtIndex:0];
        NSString* word = [stringWithHashtags substringWithRange:wordRange];

        UIColor *foregroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
        [attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:foregroundColor range:wordRange];

    }
    UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13.0f];
    [attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, stringLength)];

    return attString;
}
```

Is it possible somehow to merge the `regex` and `regexTag`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered merging the regular expression *patterns* rather than the `NSRegularExpression` instances?

Given *re1* and *re2* then the pattern *(re1)|(re2)* matches either of them. For example, *#|@* matches a # or an @. You can also match one in a set of character using *[characters in set]*.

HTH

Comment: Great idea, I changed `regularExpressionWithPattern:@"#(\\w+)"` to `regularExpressionWithPattern:@"#|@"` and it almost worked. It detected the same symbols, but somehow only the `@` & `#` is colored not the whole word. Do you have any idea how could I fix it?

Comment: Why did you miss the rest of the pattern out? Patterns are build from sub-patterns, e.g. "b(a|e)d" matches "bad" or "bed".

Comment: I've never used these kind of stuff, the pattern wasn't familiar.  I changed it for `regularExpressionWithPattern:@"#(\\w+)|@(\\w+)"`, and works fine. Are there any better solution or it is the right way?

Comment: Your pattern is fine - it works! Are there other ways? Well starting with what you first tried you could use "(#|@)(\\w+)", or if you want to go the set way then "[#@](\\w+)" will do it. Follow the `NSRegularExpression` docs and they will link through to all the basic patterns you can use and how to assemble them.